# php preg_replace doesn't work with HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I found that php preg_replace doesn't work with HTML tag.

Let's say I have such a code:

```
    $language = $this->cms_language();
    $pattern = array();
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:$language \}\}(.*)\{\{ elif_language:.*\{\{ end_if }}/";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:$language \}\}(.*)\{\{ else \}\}.*\{\{ end_if }}/";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*\{\{ elif_language:$language \}\}(.*)\{\{ elif_language:.*\{\{ end_if }}/";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*\{\{ elif_language:$language \}\}(.*)\{\{ else \}\}.*\{\{ end_if }}/";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*\{\{ else \}\}(.*)\{\{ end_if }}/"; 
    $replacement = '$1';
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
```

$this->cms_language() will return one of "english", "german" or "indonesia"

When I assign such a string to $value, it will give either "Victoria", "Hitler" or "Sule" depend on the $language's value:

```
$value = '{{ if_language:english }}Victoria{{ elif_language:german }}Hitler{{ else }}Sule{{ end_if }}</p>'
```

But it won't work when I change $value into

```
$value = '{{ if_language:english }}<br />
Victoria<br />
{{ elif_language:german }}<br />
Hitler<br />
{{ else }}<br />
Sule<br />
{{ end_if }}</p>'
```

The will give $value itself as the output.

So what's wrong here?

**EDIT** : Sorry I found this one works:

```
$value = '{{ if_language:english }}<br />Victoria<br />{{ elif_language:german }}<br /> Hitler<br />{{ else }}<br />Sule<br />{{ end_if }}';
```

So I guess the problem is with new line character, not with the <br /> tag

Comment: You're sying that you _change_ the string. How did it look like before? Did it work before? Having a short look I guess you are not using multi line expressions.

Comment: It works when the string doesn't contain any html tag (in this case <br />

Comment: You should give gettext a try. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing the right pattern modifier.

In this case you should use the `/s` modifier, e.g.:

```
/your pattern/s
```

The `/s` modifier changes how dot `.` matches characters; by default it matches everything *except* newlines, but with `/s` it truly matches anything.

Btw, you may want to also use `/U` modifier to make the expression `(.*)` non-greedy by default;  greedy patterns will try to match as much as possible and you may get unexpected results if you use them.

Multiple pattern modifiers are specified like this:

```
/your pattern/sU
```

Btw, instead of the `/U` modifier you can also use `(.*?)` to specify non-greedy matching.

Comment: This makes things more robust, especially the .*? one. Thanks for your help